# Redshift pg_user table throws Invalid Operation error on JOIN

Tags: amazon-redshift

when I run the following query,

```
select * from stl_query q
join pg_user u on q.userid = u.usesysid
where u.usename = 'admin';
```

I get the following error:

```
SQL Error [500310] [0A000]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;
```

The query is run on the leader node. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

pg_user is a Leader Node-Only Function and cannot be mixed with functions that are not Leader Node-Only.

From the documentation:

> Some Amazon Redshift SQL functions are supported only on the leader
>   node and are not supported on the compute nodes. A query that uses a
>   leader-node function must execute exclusively on the leader node, not
>   on the compute nodes, or it will return an error.
>
> The documentation for each leader-node only function includes a note
>   stating that the function **will return an error if it references
>   user-defined tables or Amazon Redshift system tables**.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_SQL_functions_leader_node_only.html

As a work around in your scenario, you can generate a temp table with the subset of pg_user data that you need, then join to that temp table.

```
select usesysid 
into temp table tmp_user
from pg_user
where usename = 'admin';

select * from stl_query q
inner join tmp_user u on q.userid = u.usesysid;
```

Comment: @Faiz Care to explain why?  If you add more detail then perhaps I can help you.